# New content appear in my website when adding iron router package

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I just added iron:router package to my meteor project and now at the end of my website it shows this

[image]

and i can't find it in my html file to delete it,

How can i remove it from my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will disappear when you add any route in your JS file. Add the following empty route to your JS file and start from there.

```
Router.route('/', function () {

});
```

Also read the iron-router docs about getting started. 
http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/

Comment: when i implement two html files, both of them being excited and appears in the home page, do you know how can i specify certain file to run, because the other i want it to be as "about us" page for the site